# Issue sending message to SQS when authenticating with cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-cognito, amazon-javascript-sdk

When attempting to send a message to sqs I get a missing config credentials warning. If switch to just displaying my accesskey and password I can send the message to sqs just fine. I've included the code I'm using and the errors I get from the browser below.

Code below:

```
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
  IdentityPoolId: 'xxxxxx',
});
var params = {
  MessageBody: 'some random message',
  QueueUrl: 'xxxxxx'
};
AWS.config.credentials.get(function(err) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  else console.log(AWS.config.credentials);
});

var sqs = new AWS.SQS();
sqs.sendMessage(params, function (err, data) {
  if (!err) {
    console.log('Message sent.');
  } else {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

Errors from console.log:

Error: Missing region in config
    at null. (https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.1.12.min.js:5:10470)
    at r.SequentialExecutor.r.util.inherit.callListeners (https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.1.12.min.js:6:27635)
    at r.SequentialExecutor.r.util.inherit.emit (https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.1.12.min.js:6:27431)
    at n.Request.o.emitEvent (https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.1.12.min.js:6:15837)
    at e (https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.1.12.min.js:6:12148)
    at r.runTo (https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.1.12.min.js:7:23197)
    at n.Request.o.runTo (https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.1.12.min.js:6:13657)
    at n.Request.o.send (https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.1.12.min.js:6:13550)
    at t.Service.i.makeUnauthenticatedRequest (https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.1.12.min.js:6:30572)
    at t.util.update.getId (https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.1.12.min.js:7:2224)
index.html:57 Error: Missing credentials in config
    at null. (https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.1.12.min.js:5:10470)
    at r.SequentialExecutor.r.util.inherit.callListeners (https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.1.12.min.js:6:27635)
    at r.SequentialExecutor.r.util.inherit.emit (https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.1.12.min.js:6:27431)
    at n.Request.o.emitEvent (https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.1.12.min.js:6:15837)
    at e (https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.1.12.min.js:6:12148)
    at r.runTo (https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.1.12.min.js:7:23197)
    at n.Request.o.runTo (https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.1.12.min.js:6:13657)
    at n.Request.o.send (https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.1.12.min.js:6:13550)
    at t.Service.i.makeUnauthenticatedRequest (https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.1.12.min.js:6:30572)
    at t.util.update.getId (https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.1.12.min.js:7:2224)

Take note that I've tried adding region various different ways.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything in your posted code that sets the region.

[Following copied from the [Configuring the SDK in Node.js](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/node-configuring.html) documentation]

The AWS SDK for Node.js doesn't select the region by default. You can choose a region similarly to setting credentials by either loading from disk or using AWS.config.update():

```
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-west-1'});
```

Comment: I've tried using that code but it complains about the region being set. I'm not using node this is just in browser javascript.

Comment: Can you post your code plus the resulting error message when you try to set the region?